# Why Does fmod Produce Different Results?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, double, modulus

I was playing around with the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double speed = 60.0;
    double distance;
    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%lf %d %d %d", &distance, &a, &b, &c);

    cout << distance <<  " " << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
    cout << (fmod((distance*3600)/speed, (a + b + c))) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and noticed that, for the following input

```
15.1 1 1 1
```

it produces this (incorrect?) result on my machine

```
15.1 1 1 1
3
```

But it seems to produce this result on ideone (http://ideone.com/mwMalv)

```
15.1 1 1 1
0
```

I realize that "0.1" (in the "15) can't be represented accurately as a double

http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

but others that have run this code with gcc 4.8.2 also obtain what's produced on ideone.

I'm running `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Desktop (32-bit)` on `VMware 6.0.5 build-2443746` with `gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)`.

What gives? Why does `fmod` behave differently on my machine than it does on others (given the compiler's the same)?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations come out to approximately `fmod(906, 3)`.  However, `906` could be `905.9999999999998532` or something, due to errors with values not being exactly representable.

The result of `fmod` with the latter than `3` will give `2.999999999999999998532` which will display as `3` when rounded to the default precision of `6`.

To see what is going on in detail, do `<< setprecision(30)` in your `cout` statements.

It also might be illuminating to inspect the assembly output generated in each case. Perhaps the compilers are doing different things; or perhaps they are doing the same thing and the FPU is different.

For example, the result of the `906` might even be done in higher precision than `double`.  Changing your code to store this in a `double` before going on to `fmod` may or may not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your detailed thoughts on this. I did as you suggested and put in a `<< setprecision(30)` and got `2.99999999999997868371792719699`. I also changed the code to store the calculations in a `double` _before_ moving to `fmod` but got the same result. I'm not sure how to inspect the assembly output, though.

Comment: in gcc compile with `-S` switch. , it will output assembly